# Color of the blockquote boxes just changed

Tags: bug, markdown

The color of the blockquote boxes (not the meta site) just changed,

> Like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94644/logic-puzzle-alphabet-splitting-extraordinaire-sequel),

from yellow to gray.
I don't know whether it's a bug or a feature, but it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this is not a bug but an intended feature, supposedly an "improvement", recently rolled out across the entire SE network:

[Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/278659)

You can support this proposal if you want it changed back:

[Please revert the quote background from white to yellow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344874/278659)

Comment: It isn't just a change in colour; the layout is different in some cases, too. If you make a spoiler block whose content is an HTML `pre` element, it gets extra space above and below compared with the old way. I think it's pretty unpleasant, but maybe there are cases that it improves.

Comment: It's also very frustrating when you have given answers to questions using images where you have coloured the 'whitespace' to match the yellow (e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/94580/60644)) - originally it looked swish, now it just looks weird! This is a trick I use quite a lot - but having given so many answers now I'll be darned if I can remember which ones I've done this on to correct them all for the new format!

Comment: @Stiv Here on this site it gets even worse: we've had a lot of puzzles which inherently revolve around some feature of the SE style or workings, so every time they change that it might invalidate some puzzles. E.g. in [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/63498/5373) "five or ten" is now wrong.